# Angular + Electron with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, typescript, electron, angular-cli, ngx-translate

I have an Angular application and now a desktop version of it is also needed. I managed it to run the application in electron and everything works as expected.

But the localization does not work. In the electron- application I only see the localization- keys which points to the actual translation in the localization files.

I mainly translate the text in Angular like this:

```
{{ "localization-key" | translate }}
```

And the translations as json-files are based in **assets/i18n/**

Does someone has an idea how to get the localization work?

Comment: Do you have any error, import to ngModule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working now. The problem was I used the Http- Loader for ngx-translate which was not working in electron.

So I implemented the **TranslateUniversalLoader** like the last post of this thread mentioned: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/754

Answer (score 7):

I also had this problem. I found the solution in the [offical documentation of ngx-translate.](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#aot)

> If you want to configure a custom TranslateLoader while using AoT
>   compilation, Ionic or **Electron**, you must use an exported function
>   instead of an inline function.

```
export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If you used default `TranslateHttpLoader` for `loader.useFactory`, you see this error:[image: i18n for wrong configuration of loader.factory for electron]