# Switch language from Angular12 menu in Electron

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, electron-forge

I have an Angular 12 app with two languages (spanish and english). In index page I have a login screen with Toolbar-menu with language selecction.

I have used i18n as way to internazionalice the app. When I build the angular app the menu to switch between languages works fine. The results language-app are 'dist/es' and 'dist/en'

The component.html code:

```
<mat-menu #idiomas="matMenu">
    <a mat-menu-item i18n href="/es">Español</a>
    <a mat-menu-item i18n href="/en">Inglés</a>
</mat-menu>
```

The main.js to inizialice Electron:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

const url = require("url");
const path = require("path");

function createWindow () {

    //Obtenemos el idioma del usuario//get user locale
    const language = app.getLocale();


    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })

    win.loadFile(__dirname+'/dist/'+language+'/index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        app.quit()
    }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow()
    }
})
```

Electron loads fine getting de user locale with: `__dirname+'/dist/'+language+'/index.html'`

When I click at language angular menu the screen becomes blanck, and I don't see anything in console

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would use ngx-translate to approach this. Please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164358/angular-electron-with-ngx-translate

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Max, but I have to use i18n Angular standard

Comment: Please be so kind and setup a stackblitz for it? Maybe this base can save you some time https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron